# chaining custom validators in express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express-validator

i thought this was pretty straightforward, but i've a feeling that chaining the custom validator with existing ones causes something strange to happen with the req object, which seems to be undefined:

```
req.checkBody('Game18awayScore', 'must be between 0 and 30').isInt({min:0, max:30}).custom((value,{ req }) => {
        console.log(something);
        if (Math.abs(value - req.body.Game18homeScore) < 2){
          if (value < 30 && req.body.Game18homeScore < 30){
            throw new Error("winning score isn't 2 greater than losing score");
          }
        }
      });
      req.checkBody('homeMan1', 'Please choose a player.').notEmpty().custom((value,{req}) => {
        if (value != 0){
          if (value == req.body.homeMan2 || value == req.body.homeMan3 || value == req.body.awayMan1 || value == req.body.awayMan2 || value == req.body.awayMan3){
            throw new Error("can't use the same player more than once")
          }
        }

      });
```

but i just keep getting:
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property`req`of 'undefined' or 'null'.`

The first custom is checking that there's a difference of at least two between the two values, unless one of the values is 30.

The second custom is checking that one value isn't being used in the other 5 options.

I should add, this block of code is in a validator Function:

`function validateScorecard (req,res,next){ [all my validations for the form including the ones above] }`

which is then included in the route:
`app.post('/scorecard-beta',validateScorecard, fixture_controller.full_fixture_post);`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.custom()` to specify an inline validator like this doesn't work when you are using the legacy API (eg `req.checkBody(...).custom()`).

The legacy API has had support for custom validators in a quite different way for some years:
You specify them as options in your express-validator middleware, and they are made available when you use `req.checkBody(...)`.
These can then receive additional arguments other than the field's value.

Example:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
    customValidators: {
        isMagicNumber(value, additionalNumbers) {
            return value === 42 || additionalNumbers.includes(value);
        }
    }
}));

app.post('/captcha', (req, res, next) => {
    // world's safest captcha implementation
    req.checkBody('answer').isMagicNumber();
    req.checkBody('answer').isMagicNumber([req.user.age]);
});
```

The `.custom()` call kinda works because the method is there, but internally in the legacy API, express-validator doesn't know how you defined it.

Your solutions?

- Keep using it like that, but refrain from using additional args, as that would come against [what is documented for `.custom()`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html).
- **stop using the legacy API, as it is deprecated and will be removed eventually**.

Comment: i went for stopping using the legacy API. i also found https://charlietheprogrammer.com/how-to-use-express-validator-5/ article incredibly helpful

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this article @BigCoops!